# What are good indicators that a question belongs on a different Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, questions

There are plenty of questions here that overlap with politics, religion, art, and so on. How should someone determine if their question would be a better fit on a different Stack than History? This may vary from question to question, but are there any 'blanket rules' that could be applied?

Comment: I think the only 'blanket rule' is "pick the site you think is best for your question, but [don't cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/437864)".

Answer (score 7):

My 2 cents (as a Stack Exchange user with many interests, including the network itself, I'm not a History.SE specialist as my reputation shows):

- A question isn't off-topic on History Stack Exchange because it's on-topic, or even *better suited*, on another site in the network; it's normal that Stack Exchange sites have some overlap.
- IMHO the best indicator is to ask yourself: what kind of experts would be best suited to answer this question? If it's historians, post it here; if it's politologists (with an interest in political history, of course), post it [there](https://politics.stackexchange.com/). Yes, there will be historians browsing the [history section of Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) and [vice versa](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-history), but less frequently than that they will be on their 'home' site.